# Homeomorphism and the matrix group??

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, analysis

Let $G$ the group of invertible real $n \times n$-matrices and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Let $aH$ and $bH$ be two classes. Prove that there is a homeomorphism $\Phi$, such that $\Phi(aH) = bH$.

I am studying Real Analysis and Topology, I should see G looks like $\mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}$??? How can I do this homeomorphism??

Comment: What group operation and topology are you using? (Addition and standard topology?)

Comment: It is the multiplicative group, I guess $Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$ and the standard topology

Comment: One suggestion: it might be more common to say "let $aH$ and $bH$ be any two cosets of $H$." (Of course, if you didn't write the problem, then you're stuck with the terminology given to you.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have in fact $G = GL(n,\mathbb R)$. If $a, b \in G$, then $d = ba^{-1} \in G$ and $\phi : G \to G, \phi(x) = dx$, is a homeomorphism with inverse $\psi(y) = d^{-1}y$. This is true because multiplication in $G$ is continuous.

But now $\phi(aH) = daH = bH$.